# C# - transfer more than one value between aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tried searching on ways to transfer more than 1 value, did manage to find a way but when running it, it only transfers one of the values and duplicates it in the second text box although I did put two different values in the textbox. Currently using Microsoft Visual Studio, which are aspx.cs files.

This is the code that is from WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?val=" + TextBox1.Text);
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?val=" + TextBox2.Text);
}
```

This is the code that is supposedly suppose to receive the values from WebForm1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["val"];
    Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["val"];
}
```

After running it, it leads to the design page, entered different values for both textboxes. After clicking the button, it leads to WebForm2.aspx, it shows the value that I had input for TextBox1 in both Label1 and Label2. The value which was in TextBox2 is no where to be found. I'm fairly new to C# coding so I have no idea on where I went wrong.

Comment: &val2=SomethingElse

Comment: Note that `Response.Redirect` in ASP.NET WebForms raises a ThreadAbortException after having generated its output, so the second `Response.Redirect` (or any other code you may have there) is never executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate variables in the querystring are separated by an ampersand

> WebForm2.aspx?val1=foo&val2=bar

As you see, you'll need differing variables names

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?val1=" + TextBox1.Text + "&val2=" + TextBox2.Text);
```

and

```
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["val1"];
Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["val2"];
```

Comment: To enhance this even further, I'd suggest to use `Server.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text)` instead of just `TextBox1.Text` (etc), otherwise non-alphabetical/non-numeric characters in theTextboxes may cause the URL to malfunction or misbehave.

Comment: @PeterB not to mention using [`Server.HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx) before adding it to a label to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: Yup, indeed. We should try pair programming one day :-)